# Plastic SCM: Root element is missing

Tags: plasticscm

Symptom: Unable to start PlasticSCM.

Error: Root element is missing.

Full text of error: "the client configuration file "client.conf""

Actions:

I tried reinstalling. I have also tried running the configure command.

What to do?

Comment: @jsotola the error says "the client configuration file "client.conf" contains errors: Root element is missing. 

p.s. My apologies for not including it the first time. It showed in the draft but didn't publish.

Comment: I have updated the question to contain the text from the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Delete "client.conf" under "C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\plastic4"
2. Rerun the "cm configure" command and/or reinstall.

Those files are not deleted under reinstallation to not break the configuration between upgrades. Thus they have to be deleted manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete client.conf with all GUIs closed so it rebuilds next start, its located in the hidden folder Users/youruser/.plastic4 (Mac) or Users/youruser/appdata/local/plastic4 (windows).

If the problem persists you can contact PlasticSCM support at support@codicesoftware.com